# D3.js map zoom behaviors in canvas and svg

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, d3.js

Thanks for reading.

**The Goal**

I would like to compare a working SVG click-to-zoom from Mike Bostock's blocks to a canvas-based system. I've placed the working SVG on the top, and a canvas on the bottom. When a user clicks on a state in the upper SVG, I would like the lower canvas element to "follow", or mimic, the zooming and panning. For example, clicking Minnesota in the upper SVG will also cause the lower canvas to zoom and pan to Minnesota.

**The Problem**

My canvas element draws fine after loading the topojson, but it does not animate. I would like it to animate.  I believe this is because I do not fully understand zoom behaviors and path-based projections.

http://jsfiddle.net/30w8nv4t/2/

```
function zoomed(d) {
  g.style("stroke-width", 1.5 / d3.event.scale + "px");
  g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");

  // the zTranslate and zScale variables appear to be ok,
  // but `d` is null. I'm not sure how to redraw.
  var zTranslate = zoom.translate();
  var zScale = zoom.scale();
  console.log(zTranslate, zScale, d);
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  context.beginPath();
  canvasPath(d);
  context.stroke();
}
```

In this case, `d` is clearly null, and I'm not able to redraw anything. I assume my problem could be in either the `zoomed` method or in the `clicked` function.

**The Reason**

I am using this side-by-side approach because I would like to learn how paths, projections, and zoom behaviors work together. I admire how well canvas performs against SVG, but the lack of interactivity is daunting. Fortunately, being able to zoom and pan to arbitrary geometry cuts my problem in half.

Thank you for reading.  The link to JSFiddle is at the top of this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `canvas` drawing function uses the projected values of the lat/long co-ordinates, but you're not updating the `scale` and `translate` of your `projection` in your `zoom` handler.

One way to get the behavior that you're after, is to switch from a `transform` on the `svg` in the `zoom` handler, to a `transform` on the `projection`.

I have done just that in this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/30w8nv4t/7/

The differences are:

1. Update the `zoom` behavior to use the `projection` `translate` and `scale` as the default values, and to set the `scaleExtent` values to be based on the `projection` as well.

   ```
   var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
       .translate(projection.translate())
       .scale(projection.scale())
       .scaleExtent([projection.scale()/5, projection.scale()*5])
       .on("zoom", zoomed);
   ```
2. Update your `zoomed` function to `translate` and `scale` the `projection` and then redraw the `svg` based paths.

   ```
   function zoomed(d) {
     //g.style("stroke-width", 1.5 / d3.event.scale + "px");
     //g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
     projection.translate(d3.event.translate).scale(d3.event.scale);
     g.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);

     var zTranslate = zoom.translate();
     var zScale = zoom.scale();
     console.log(zTranslate, zScale, d);
     context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
     context.beginPath();
     canvasPath(states);
     context.stroke();
   }
   ```
3. Update your `clicked` function accordingly.

   ```
   function clicked(d) {
       if (active.node() === this) {
           zoom.scale(500).translate([width/2, height/2]);
           active.classed("active", false);
           active = d3.select(null);
       } else {
           var centroid = path.centroid(d),
               translate = zoom.translate(),
               bounds = path.bounds(d),
               dx = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0],
               dy = bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1],
               scale = .9/ Math.max(dx / width, dy / height);

           zoom.scale(scale * zoom.scale())
                     .translate([
                         translate[0] - centroid[0] * scale + width *  scale / 2, 
                         translate[1] - centroid[1] * scale + height * scale / 2]);


           active.classed("active", false);
           active = d3.select(this).classed("active", true);
       }

       zoom.event(svg);
   }
   ```

   This is probably one of the major components of the change, as the `scale` and `translate` are applied to the `zoom` behavior, and when they are, they have to be scaled by the current `zoom` `scale`.  The `clicked` function then fires the `zoomed` function to redraw the `svg` and `canvas` elements.

As you can see, your `canvas` drawing code was correct.  It was just that the drawing code of was using the `projection` to determine the `x` and `y` positions of the points to draw based on the `projection` which wasn't being updated by the `zoom` handler.

It would also be possible to have a separate `projection` for the `canvas`, and update that in the `zoom` handler before calling the `canvas` redraw functions.  I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader!

Comment: Good, this pushes me in a much better direction. It seems that it gets a little buggy when we combine mouse-zoom with clicking, though. For example, click California. Note that the map zooms on California. Now drag the map around eastward and click on a state. observe that the state is not centered.  That being said, this pushed me to understand the role of zoom behaviors and projections. My drawing function was correct! :)